# Getting warning "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." when my component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get rid of this warning in my react app:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `SettingRadioButtonGroup`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
    at SettingRadioButtonGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92979:171)
    at div
    at CardBody (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:56308:27)
    at div
    at Transition (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:85807:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:50905:22
    at AccordionCollapse (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49335:23)
    at div
    at Card (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49995:23)
    at div
    at SettingGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92935:15)
    at TestSettingGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:93093:22)
    at div
    at Accordion (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49282:96)
    at div
    at ModalBody (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:56308:27)
    at div
    at div
    at ModalDialog (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:53383:23)
    at div
    at Transition (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:85807:30)
    at Fade (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:51637:24)
    at DialogTransition
    at Modal (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:84195:24)
    at Modal (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:53061:23)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92660:22)
```

Here is the code of my `SettingRadioButtonGroup` components:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

export type RadioButtonGroup = {
  desc: string;
  isSelected: boolean;
};

export interface SettingRadioButtonGroupProps
{
  groupDesc: string;
  radioButtons: RadioButtonGroup[];
  onRadioSelected: (selectedItem: string) => void;
};

export function SettingRadioButtonGroup(props: SettingRadioButtonGroupProps)
{
  const radioGroupName = nanoid();
  return (
    <div className="radio-group">
      <p className="radio-label">{props.groupDesc}</p>
      <div className="group">
        {
          props.radioButtons.map((button) =>
          {
            if (button.isSelected)
              props.onRadioSelected(button.desc);

            const buttonLabel = nanoid();
            return (
              <div className="radio-button">
                <input type="radio" id={buttonLabel} name={radioGroupName} onClick={() => { () => props.onRadioSelected(button.desc) }} />
                <label htmlFor={radioGroupName}>{button.desc}</label>
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the component that generate this components:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { TextBoxSetting } from "./Components/TextBoxSetting";
import { SettingGroup } from "./Components/SettingGroup";
import SettingGroupBaseProps from "./Components/SettingGroupBaseProps";
import { RadioButtonGroup, SettingRadioButtonGroup } from "./Components/SettingRadioButtonGroup";
import faker from  "faker/locale/fr_CA";

export default function TestSettingGroup(props: SettingGroupBaseProps)
{
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState<string>();

  const radioButton: RadioButtonGroup[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    radioButton.push({
      desc: faker.lorem.word(),
      isSelected: false
    })
  }

  const [buttonSelected, setButtonSelected] = useState<string>();
  import("lodash")
    .then((_) =>
    {
      const selected = _.find(radioButton, (value) => value.isSelected);
      if (selected)
        setButtonSelected(selected.desc);
    })
    .catch();



  function onSave()
  {

    const settings = {
      textBoxSetting: textInput,
      radioButtonSelected: buttonSelected
    };

    console.table(settings);
  }


  return (
    <SettingGroup name={props.name} desc={props.desc} onSave={onSave}>
      <TextBoxSetting onTextEntered={(e) => setTextInput(e)} name="Text box setting component" />
      <SettingRadioButtonGroup groupDesc={"Radio button group"} radioButtons={radioButton} onRadioSelected={setButtonSelected} />
    </SettingGroup>
  );
}
```

I tried to get rid of the warning by assigning a random id to the key property as follow however I still have the warning and it caused the component to create a bug where it generate an new radio button when I click a radio button. It also create the following warning:

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `tvehx36gLi-hG56z68RTg`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at SettingRadioButtonGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92980:171)
    at div
    at CardBody (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:56308:27)
    at div
    at Transition (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:85807:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:50905:22
    at AccordionCollapse (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49335:23)
    at div
    at Card (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49995:23)
    at div
    at SettingGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92935:15)
    at TestSettingGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:93094:22)
    at div
    at Accordion (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49282:96)
    at div
    at ModalBody (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:56308:27)
    at div
    at div
    at ModalDialog (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:53383:23)
    at div
    at Transition (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:85807:30)
    at Fade (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:51637:24)
    at DialogTransition
    at Modal (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:84195:24)
    at Modal (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:53061:23)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92660:22)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2430
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:67
error @ react-dom.development.js:43
warnOnInvalidKey @ react-dom.development.js:13620
reconcileChildrenArray @ react-dom.development.js:13651
reconcileChildFibers @ react-dom.development.js:14125
reconcileChildren @ react-dom.development.js:16990
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17632
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19080
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23940
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:646
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22420
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
9react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `wFq9eikLw6B_LN98bUqCV`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at SettingRadioButtonGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92980:171)
    at div
    at CardBody (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:56308:27)
    at div
    at Transition (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:85807:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:50905:22
    at AccordionCollapse (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49335:23)
    at div
    at Card (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49995:23)
    at div
    at SettingGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92935:15)
    at TestSettingGroup (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:93094:22)
    at div
    at Accordion (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:49282:96)
    at div
    at ModalBody (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:56308:27)
    at div
    at div
    at ModalDialog (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:53383:23)
    at div
    at Transition (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:85807:30)
    at Fade (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:51637:24)
    at DialogTransition
    at Modal (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:84195:24)
    at Modal (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:53061:23)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/main_window/index.js:92660:22)
```

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { RadioButtonGroup } from "./SettingRadioButtonGroup";


export interface SettingCheckboxButtonGroupProps
{
  groupDesc: string;
  checkboxButtons: RadioButtonGroup[];
  onCheckboxSelected: (selectedItem: string) => void;
};

export function SettingChecboxButtonGroup(props: SettingCheckboxButtonGroupProps)
{
  const radioGroupName = nanoid();
  return (
    <div className="radio-group">
      <p className="radio-label">{props.groupDesc}</p>
      <div className="group">
        {
          props.checkboxButtons.map((button) =>
          {
            if (button.isSelected)
              props.onCheckboxSelected(button.desc);

            const buttonLabel = nanoid();
            return (
              <div className="radio-button">
                <input key={radioGroupName} type="checkbox" id={buttonLabel} name={radioGroupName} onClick={() => { () => props.onCheckboxSelected(button.desc); }} />
                <label key={radioGroupName} htmlFor={radioGroupName}>{button.desc}</label>
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need `<div className="radio-button" key={button.desc}>`

Comment: The key should be on the mapped return value (the div). If you're generating dupe random keys then it's likely there's a problem in that logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the key on the outer-most element in the `map`.

Element keys only distinguish an element from its siblings relative to their parent. Here the `div`s are the siblings that need to be distinguished, rather than the `input` or `label` elements.

Example:

```js
<div key={radioGroupName} className="radio-button">
    <input type="checkbox" id={buttonLabel} name={radioGroupName} onClick={() => { () => props.onCheckboxSelected(button.desc); }} />
    <label htmlFor={radioGroupName}>{button.desc}</label>
</div>
```

Also keys serve to give dynamically generated elements (in a loop/`map`) a stable identity, so I wouldn't recommend using randomly generated keys unless you're storing those in state so that they're stable as well (if all the keys are regenerated and change on every rerender, there is no point in assigning keys). Check out the [docs on keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for more info.

Comment: This is key answer.  The react docs do not say it has to be in the outer-most element and I thought I was following along step by step.

Answer (score 0):

In React, every time you ara going to render a sequence of items from an array, using for example a `map` function, you have to provide a **unique key** for every item to help React's engine recognize each one, in your example, you can do something like this to fix:

```js
props.radioButtons.map((button, index) =>
  {
    if (button.isSelected)
      props.onRadioSelected(button.desc);

    const buttonLabel = nanoid();
    return (
      <div key={buttonLabel} className="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" id={buttonLabel} name={radioGroupName} onClick={() => { () => props.onRadioSelected(button.desc) }} />
        <label htmlFor={radioGroupName}>{button.desc}</label>
      </div>
    );
  })
}
```

Check the change at `<div key={buttonLabel} className="radio-button">`